# How can I place a list inside ASP.NET datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, datalist

I apologize if the answer to this seems obvious but I just cannot figure it out myself.
I am building a web application and have come to the stage where I need to get data from the database and display it in a datalist.

I am aiming for the following output in my datalist:

Question 1 Name
   Answer 1
   Answer 2
   ...
   Answer 8
Question 2 Name
   Answer 1
   Answer 2
   ...
   Answer 8
Question 3 Name
   Answer 1
   ....

You get the idea.
I have written out a basic datalist starting with the questions (code below) which works to some extent,however I am not quite sure how to approach getting the answers out and then repeating the process until all the data has been fetched.
Here is the code.
**Confirm.aspx**

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" id="dgQuestionnaire">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Name" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QuestionText") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:DataList>
```

**Confirm.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class Confirm_Questionnaire : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        OsqarSQL GetData;
        DataTable DT;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetData = new OsqarSQL();
            int questionnaireId = (int)Session["QuestionnaireID"];
            string questionnaireName = (string)Session["QuestionnaireName"];
            ReturnQnrName.Text = questionnaireName + "   (ID: " + questionnaireId.ToString() + ")";
            int questionId = GetData.GetQuestionID(questionnaireId);
            DT = GetData.GetQuestionName(questionnaireId);
            dgQuestionnaire.DataSource = DT;
            dgQuestionnaire.DataBind();

        } // End Page_Load

    } // Emd Class Confirm_Questionnaire
```

**Questionnaire.cs (App_Code)**

```
public class OsqarSQL
    {
        private string _productConnectionString;
        private SqlConnection _productConn;

        public OsqarSQL()
        {
            _productConn = new SqlConnection();
            _productConnectionString += "data source=mssql.database.co.uk; Initial Catalog=devworks_oscar;User ID=me;Password=you";
            _productConn.ConnectionString = _productConnectionString;
        }
        public DataTable GetQuestionName(int QuestionnaireID)
        {
            string returnValue = string.Empty;
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("GetQuestion", _productConn);
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@QUEST_ID", SqlDbType.Int));
            myCommand.Parameters[0].Value = QuestionnaireID;
            return createDataTable(getData(myCommand));
        }
        public DataTable GetAnswerTitle(int QuestionnaireID)
        {
            string returnValue = string.Empty;
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("GetAnswer", _productConn);
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@QUEST_ID", SqlDbType.Int));
            myCommand.Parameters[0].Value = QuestionnaireID;
            return createDataTable(getData(myCommand));
        }
```

I know i am missing something but I am not sure what to include in order to display the answers with each question.

Thanks
Idny,

Comment: Good question, and nicely structured code.  You can probably remove your data access layer code though since its functionality is implied, is not a direct part of the question, and makes the question much longer than it needs to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you can put a `DataList` inside the `ItemTemplate` of another `DataList`.

You link them using the `DataKeyField` property.

This [tutorial](http://www.ezineasp.net/post/ASP-Net-Nested-DataList-Control-using-C-sharp.aspx) walks you through it.

Comment: Yep the problem OP faces calls for nested databound controls.  A `Repeater` within the outer `DataList` might also be a good choice.

Comment: Tutorial provided the correct method. Just trying to move the data reader to a .cs in App_Code whilst keeping the data binding on the aspx.cs page. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. 
I guess what you are trying to do is get all the questions from the DB and then display all answers corresponding to a question below that question.

You can try to use a repeater. Basically there would be two repeaters, one inside the another. The outer repeater would display questions from the datasource and the inner one would display answers for that particular question.